# How to get CreatedBy field for the SPListItem folder?

Tags: sharepoint

Is there any way you can get `CreatedBy` field for `SPListItem Folder`. I got `CreatedDate` using `SPListitem.Folder.Properties` but not able to get `CreatedBy` field.

Thanks,

Ashish Chotalia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SPListItem.Folder.Item["CreatedBy"].

Answer (score 0):

One of answers that worked for me too:

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].ToString());
SPUser author = userValue.User;
```